# A directory magically turns into file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I create a directory in the `viewDidLoad` at the Documents folder of my app.

```
NSString *localDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
self.projectsLocalPath = [localDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Projects"];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:self.projectsLocalPath] == NO) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:self.projectsLocalPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
}
```

After that, I list all files so that they appear in logs, checking wether it is a directory or not:

```
//----- LIST ALL FILES -----
NSArray *contentOfFolder = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:localDirectory error:nil];
for (NSString *aPath in contentOfFolder) {
    NSString *fullPath = [localDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aPath];
    
    BOOL isDir;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
        NSLog(@"%@ - IT IS A DIR", fullPath);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@ - IT IS NOT A DIR", fullPath);
    }
}
```

When I first run the app, the log files list look like this:

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E3...94/Documents/Project.sqlite - IT IS NOT A DIR
>
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E3...94/Documents/Project.sqlite-shm - IT IS NOT A DIR
>
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E3...94/Documents/Project.sqlite-wal - IT IS NOT A DIR
>
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E3...94/Documents/Projects - IT IS A DIR

Everything is correct. But the following runs show in the logs that the `Projects` folder is not a directory anymore.

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E3...94/Documents/Project.sqlite - IT IS NOT A DIR
>
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E3...94/Documents/Project.sqlite-shm - IT IS NOT A DIR
>
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E3...94/Documents/Project.sqlite-wal - IT IS NOT A DIR
>
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E3...94/Documents/Projects - IT IS NOT A DIR

It is like it converts magically into a file... The problem is that when I want to see the directory's contents, I'm getting an error saying that it is NOT a directory.

Am I doing anything wrong? This problem is driving me nuts...

Thank you all for your help in advance.

**EDIT:**

At the first run, once directory is created, I download some files and save them into the newly created directory using the dropbox API: `[self.restClient loadFile:plan.path intoPath:self.projectsLocalPath];`. There is no error when saving files into this directory.

Comment: What happens between the first and the second run? Are they independent? The result is randomly?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad At the first run, once directory is created, I download some files and save them into the newly created directory using the dropbox API: `[self.restClient loadFile:plan.path intoPath:self.projectsLocalPath];`. There is no error when saving files into this directory.

Comment: I created a sample project copied all your code in my viewDidLoad. I'm not getting any issues, everytime that shows as a directory in my Log !!! The directory GUID will be different in each run, but in your case that is similar, why is that ? Are you hardcoding that ?

Comment: @KrLx_roller And when do you start the second run? Immediately after downloading the files?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I wait for the three files to be downloaded and saved. Then, I rerun the app and the directory it seems to be now a file.

Comment: I ask, because I can imagine that dropbox replaces the directory with a compressed file, completes the download and then decompresses it to a directory.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I've waited about three minutes (enough to get the files supposedly decompressed) but same results...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By calling:

```
[self.restClient loadFile:plan.path intoPath:self.projectsLocalPath];
```

you're asking the rest client to place the file at the folder location - replacing the folder - not placing it in the folder.

You need to create a full path to the destination file, including the file name inside the folder.

Comment: There must be explicit code in that method to check the existing file and remove it, before writing the new file.

Comment: @trojanfoe There is, in the `DBRequest` class, it moves the temporary file into the final location removing anything currently there

Comment: Done! I just added the full path including the file name and extension and voilá, working! `NSString *newFilePath = [self.projectsLocalPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:plan.filename];
            [self.restClient loadFile:plan.path intoPath:newFilePath];`

Comment: @trojanfoe omg you are right! I'm so happy to solve the problem that I don't mind writing extra useless code haha. Thank you for pointing that! :)